# How to determine when you have won in 3d tic tac toe?

Tags: java, arrays, tic-tac-toe

I have a board:

```
int board[][][] = new int[4][4][4];
```

I have been provided with a list of all the possible lines on the 4x4x4 array.

```
static final int[][][] lines = {
    {{0,0,0},{0,0,1},{0,0,2},{0,0,3}},  //lev 0; row 0   rows in each lev
    {{0,1,0},{0,1,1},{0,1,2},{0,1,3}},  //       row 1     
    {{0,2,0},{0,2,1},{0,2,2},{0,2,3}},    
    {{0,3,0},{0,3,1},{0,3,2},{0,3,3}},     
    {{1,0,0},{1,0,1},{1,0,2},{1,0,3}},  
    {{1,1,0},{1,1,1},{1,1,2},{1,1,3}},    
    {{1,2,0},{1,2,1},{1,2,2},{1,2,3}},     
    ............ and so on....
```

The method

```
checkWin(int board[][][])
```

should return `board[x][y][z]`, where the index at `[x][y][z]` is  either X or O on a the winning line.

I don't understand how to get java to recognize whether there are 4 X's or O's in a row using this set of arrays provided.

I know that there is a manual way of doing this in that I could type:

```
if((board[0][0][0] == board[0][0][1])
&& (board[0][0][1] == board[0][0][2])
&& (board[0][0][2] == board[0][0][3]))
        return board[0][0][0];

if((board[0][1][0] == board[0][1][1])
&& (board[0][1][1] == board[0][1][2])
&& (board[0][1][2] == board[0][1][3]))
        return board[0][1][0];
```

76 times for each line but that seems extremely tedious.

Comment: Try to understand what's the relation between each index and think about generalizing it with loops.

Comment: what are values 0 1 2 3 in your cells?